# Calculating derivative of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $e^{\operatorname{Log}(z)} = z$ and use this to evaluate the derivative of the function Log(z).

I have done the first part like this:

Letting $z = re^{i\theta}$,

$$
\begin{align}
e^{\operatorname{Log}(z)} & = e^{\operatorname{Log}(re^i\theta)} \\ \\
& = e^{\log r + i(\theta + 2k\pi)} \\  \\
& = e^{\log(r)}e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)} \\  \\
& = r[\cos(\theta + 2k\pi) + i\sin(\theta + 2k\pi)] \\  \\
& = r[\cos(\theta\pi) + i\sin(\theta)] \\  \\
& = re^{i\theta} = z
\end{align}
$$

But I can't see how I am supposed to make use of that to calculate the derivative of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$.

Comment: Differentiate both sides of the first equation, maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have $e^{\log z} = z$ from above. Differentiating both sides in respect to $z$ using chain rule, we have (knowing that $\frac{d}{dz}e^z=e^z$ and $\frac{d}{dz}z = 1$):

$$e^{\log z}\log' z = z \log'z=1 \Rightarrow \log' z = \frac{1}{z}$$

So thus we have

$$\frac{d}{dz}\log z = \frac{1}{z}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the chain rule:
$$
1=\frac{d}{dz} z = \frac{d}{dz} e^{\operatorname{Log} z} = e^{\operatorname{Log} z} \; \operatorname{Log}' z = z\; \operatorname{Log}' z.
$$
So
$$
1 = z\;\operatorname{Log}' z.
$$
Divide both sides by $z$.